# How to find if line or text have specific word from wordlist?

Tags: linux, grep, terminal, solaris

I have a line (alarm) and a wordlist. I want to check if the line contains any word from the wordlist, or not, using terminal command. I tried [`grep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html), but did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your list of words in a file.
e.g. /tmp/wordlist.txt

```
dog  
cat  
horse  
mouse
```

Then
`$ echo "your line" | grep -F -f /tmp/wordlist.txt`
If your 'line' contains one of the words in the list, the line will be printet and the exit status will be 0.

Comment: it print illegal option on -F and -f, is it an team administrator issue or different versions?

Comment: What System and Os are you using?

Comment: Oracle solaris from ericsson, known as oss

Comment: Sorry, don't know that one. Maybe you can look up the parameter for your version of grep or fgrep with 'man grep' or 'man fgrep'.

Comment: Just found this Oracle 11.2 man page (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/grep-1.html). It seem there might be a different version of grep (/usr/xpg4/bin/grep) on your system which understands the -f and -F options.

Comment: that's great, is there anyway to use the xpg4/bin/grep instead of the bin/grep as my default grep command?

Comment: just use '/usr/xpg4/bin/grep' instead of 'grep'

Comment: this helped me alot, many thanks :))

Comment: is there any way to make the grep output is the matched line from the file not the same text?

Comment: @Null try the '-o' option if you only want the matched text as an output

Answer (score 0):

`grep` with `-F` option should work. The image shows a simple example with multiple keywords to match (separated by newline)'. The example is taking input from the console. Using the image below for highlighted matches.

[image: The image shows a simple example of how the <code>-F</code> option of <code>grep</code> works to match some text from the console against multiple keywords (separated by newline)'.]